# How to execute a postgres query with multiple dynamic parameters using python

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to execute a postgres select query using `cursor.execute`. How can I write the query if the number of parameters change dynamically.

E.g

One instance the query can be

```
cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM personal_details WHERE id IN (%s, %s)', (3, 4))
```

an in some other instance the query can be

```
cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM personal_details WHERE id IN (%s, %s, %s)', (3, 4, 5))
```

If the parameters are available in a list as `ids = [3, 4]` or `ids = [3, 4, 5]` what is the proper way of writing this query

I tried with the following code

```
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM personal_details WHERE id IN param = %s", [ids['param']])
```

But it returned with an error saying *TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str*

Comment: Is `ids` a list? If it is, the part where it says "param = %s" doesn't seem like it makes sense. Maybe you mean `WHERE id in %s` ?

Comment: You are right. I though the list ids will be copied to param and then it will be used as the parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to build your statement dynamically:

```
params = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
sql = f"SELECT x FROM tbl WHERE id IN ({', '.join(['%s']*len(params))})"
print(sql)
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

Output of print:

```
SELECT x FROM tbl WHERE id IN (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
```

Comment: Thank for the response .. Thrying this solution and will update here

Comment: Actually if you are doing this you need to use the  [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16) and [psycopg2 list adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM personal_details WHERE id IN param = ANY(%s)", [ids])
```